# Function changeTarget() it's failing

Tags: sumo

I'm running a simulation in which is required that every car stays in it. So when a car it's reaching its final destination I tried to change it using the `changeTarget()` function from the traci library.

Being specific, I'm using the `getRoute` and `getRouteIndex` functions to know if the vehicle is at the end of the route and using `changeTarget` to set the new route, which theoretically should be created by the command. However, an error code keeps showing up: `traci.exceptions.TraCIException : Route replacement failed for 13`

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3, SUMO 1.3.1 and using the os, sys, optparse, subprocess, random, math libraries.

The part of the code which contains `changeTarget` its that:

```
if step >= 12:      #starts the contamination
            car_matrix_actualized = traci.vehicle.getIDList()   #gets the cars who are in the simulation in the new step
            for i in car_matrix_actualized:
                if traci.vehicle.getRouteIndex(str(i)) == (len(traci.vehicle.getRoute(str(i))) - 1): #verification to see if the car is at the end of its route
                    new_destiny = random.choice(traci.edge.getIDList())
                    traci.vehicle.changeTarget(str(i),str(new_destiny))
```

The whole code its in this link: https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/6168

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/6172. The essence is that you need to make sure that your new destination is a "real" edge (no junction internal edge) and, that your vehicle is allowed on this edge and that it is connected to your current position.